.select does not trigger
I want to create some circle on point clicked on a gradio image, here's my code
import gradio as gr
import numpy as np
#from Modules import calcs
# Global list to store clicked points
clicked_points = []
def draw_circle_on_img(img, center, radius=10, color=[255, 0, 0]):
    """Draw a circle on the image with the given radius and color."""
    y, x = center
    height, width, _ = img.shape
    rr, cc = np.ogrid[:height, :width]
    dist = (rr - y) ** 2 + (cc - x) ** 2
    mask = dist <= radius ** 2
    img[mask] = color
    return img

def get_click_coords(img, evt: gr.SelectData):
    print("CLICKED")
    global clicked_points
    out = img.copy()
    if len(clicked_points) < 5:
        clicked_points.append((evt.index[0], evt.index[1]))

        # Draw a circle around each clicked point
        for x, y in clicked_points:
            out = draw_circle_on_img(out, (y, x), radius=4, color=[0, 255, 255])  # Red color for circles
    
        # Return the updated image for both input and output
    return out,img
def reset(img):
    print("RESET")
    global clicked_points
    clicked_points = []
    return img, img

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    with gr.Row():
        input_img = gr.Image(label="Input", type="numpy")
        output_img = gr.Image(label="Image with Clicks", type="numpy")
        # Function to handle click events and update both images
        input_img.select(get_click_coords, [input_img], [input_img, output_img])
        input_img.upload(reset, [input_img], [input_img, input_img])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo.launch()

And the RESET does print, but not the CLICKED, It doesn't error, doesn't crash or anything, just does not register at all, It doesn't even create the targeting cursor when hover over.
this code is actually modified from an original code, which I broke due to my editing, at which point I reverted back and I still cant click it, I deleted all the unnecessary code, and its still broken, I've restarted my pc, Still broken

Hmm, I can't even get their demo code working: https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/blob/main/demo/image_selections/run.py

Me too, But this used to work like a few days ago
